# Public static final declaration of an instance variables in JAVA Interfaces

Tags: java, interface

Why we use `public static final` declaration of instance variables in a Java Interface?
All the variables are implicitly `public static final` in a Java Interface. 
Is it a good coding practice to use `public static final` in constant variable although it is declared inside an Interface.

**For example :**

```
public interface TestInterface{

public static final String EX_CONSTANT = "ABC";
public static final int EX_INT_CONSTANT = 5;
public static final double EX_DOUBLE = 5.0;
public static final Integer EX_INTEGER = 10;

}
```

Comment: You can make variables of interface type if the interface is implemented by the class? I have read that this is a better way of creating a variable in a class because if you add new methods you do not have to change every instance of the variable with in the class. class A implement Binterface {  Binterface = myInterface; then ic an call the methods in the interface just like a regular class definition. Why woudl this be the case and what benefit would I can from such a declaration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use of uniform syntax in both classes and interfaces simplifies refactoring.

You may want to turn your `interface` into a `class` somewhere in future, or move these fields into a class, and you'll get a semantical difference if you overlook some fields defined without `public static final` (of course, we have tools for refactoring, but nonetheless).

I think it's the same thing as support of `@Overriden` annotation for implementations of methods declared in interfaces that was introduced in Java 6 - it's redundant in its current form, but may become useful in case of refactoring.

Comment: plenty of 'in the present' bugs and SO questions would also be averted if people used @Override :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so. All *interface* variables are implicitly public static final so no meaning to mark them same.

Answer (score 4):

From the book Effective java by JOshua Bloch

> **Item 19: Use interfaces only to define types**
>
> When a class implements an interface, the interface serves as a type that can
>   be used to refer to instances of the class. That a class implements an interface
>   should therefore say something about what a client can do with instances of the
>   class. It is inappropriate to define an interface for any other purpose.
>
> One kind of interface that fails this test is the so-called constant interface.
>   Such an interface contains no methods; it consists solely of static final fields, each
>   exporting a constant. Classes using these constants implement the interface to
>   avoid the need to qualify constant names with a class name. Here is an example:

```
// Constant interface antipattern - do not use!
public interface PhysicalConstants {
    // Avogadro's number (1/mol)
    static final double AVOGADROS_NUMBER = 6.02214199e23;
    // Boltzmann constant (J/K)
    static final double BOLTZMANN_CONSTANT = 1.3806503e-23;
    // Mass of the electron (kg)
    static final double ELECTRON_MASS = 9.10938188e-31;
}
```

> The constant interface pattern is a poor use of interfaces. That a class uses
>   some constants internally is an implementation detail. Implementing a constant
>   interface causes this implementation detail to leak into the class’s exported API. It
>   is of no consequence to the users of a class that the class implements a constant
>   interface. In fact, it may even confuse them. Worse, it represents a commitment: if
>   in a future release the class is modified so that it no longer needs to use the constants,
>   it still must implement the interface to ensure binary compatibility. If a
>   nonfinal class implements a constant interface, all of its subclasses will have their
>   namespaces polluted by the constants in the interface.
>
> There are several constant interfaces in the Java platform libraries, such as
>   java.io.ObjectStreamConstants. These interfaces should be regarded as
>   anomalies and should not be emulated.
>
> If you want to export constants, there are several reasonable choices. If the
>   constants are strongly tied to an existing class or interface, you should add them to
>   the class or interface. For example, all of the boxed numerical primitive classes,
>   such as Integer and Double, export MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE constants. If the
>   constants are best viewed as members of an enumerated type, you should export
>   them with an enum type (Item 30). Otherwise, you should export the constants
>   with a noninstantiable utility class (Item 4). Here is a utility class version of the
>   PhysicalConstants example above:

```
// Constant utility class
package com.effectivejava.science;

public class PhysicalConstants {
    private PhysicalConstants() {
    } // Prevents instantiation

    public static final double AVOGADROS_NUMBER = 6.02214199e23;
    public static final double BOLTZMANN_CONSTANT = 1.3806503e-23;
    public static final double ELECTRON_MASS = 9.10938188e-31;
}
```

> Normally a utility class requires clients to qualify constant names with a class
>   name, for example, PhysicalConstants.AVOGADROS_NUMBER. If you make heavy
>   use of the constants exported by a utility class, you can avoid the need for qualifying
>   the constants with the class name by making use of the static import facility,
>   introduced in release 1.5:

```
// Use of static import to avoid qualifying constants
import static com.effectivejava.science.PhysicalConstants.*;
public class Test {
    double atoms(double mols) {
        return AVOGADROS_NUMBER * mols;
    }
...
// Many more uses of PhysicalConstants justify static import
}
```

> In summary, interfaces should be used only to define types. They should not
>   be used to export constants.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, Interface is a contract. Once variables are declared or defined they are not going to change. That's why generally we make them `public static final`.

Readability is another factor which makes declaration redundant.

Comment: But the variables in interface by default public,static and final. So , why we need to use those keywords?

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly, it's redundant. Usually people just don't know that they're implicitly `public static final` and declare it anyway. Ditto with things like declaring:

```
public abstract interface Test { // Interfaces are always abstract
    public void testMethod(); // Interface methods are always public
    abstract void anotherTestMethod(); // Also redundant
}
```

Usually it just boils down to the fact that people don't know that they don't *have* to declare it one way or the other. I once talked to someone (who was a seasoned programmer) that thought the `default` case in `switch` is required or it won't compile.

That being said, the only argument to be made for adding them is that they clarify what their actual visibility and whatnot actually is. It's a matter of readability and clarification, and whether or note to include them is irrelevant in terms of how it actually behaves.

Comment: Why we use abstract interface? As interface is implicitly abstract.

Comment: That's my point is that some people include it simply to clarify that it's abstract or because they don't know they don't need to add it. There's no functional reason to use it, only subjective reasons that vary from person to person

Answer (score 2):

When you are working in a team of programmers, you will find junior programmers who do not know the fact that by default the variables are **public static final** in the interface, and seeing the variables declared that way will give them extra information about the interface and the use of its variables.

Comment: You could always tell them, or they could always learn the language.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: it is redundant. I don't like to add redundant syntax at any time. However the practice does has its adherents. Some also like to add parentheses around return-expressions, on the fallacious grounds that it's like an 'if' statement; extra parentheses to 'clarify' arithmetic expressions that a third-grader would understand; etc. It's all part of the rich tapestry of life.